# What is called the thing that other things are dependent on?

Tags: word-request, terminology

I wrote:

> Moreover, we don't use the *children* tag for the dependents. Instead, we directly add them to **the  node they are dependent on** as child nodes.

I know *dependent* means something like X that depends on Y, but what is called Y? Is there a name for the bold part in my sentence?

Maybe, considering the context, I just need to omit the *they are dependent on* and use only *the node*?

Like this:

> Moreover, we don't use the *children* tag for the dependents of **a node**. Instead, we directly add them to **the  node** as child nodes.

Comment: *parent* node, perhaps?

Comment: I think there is one point that everyone seems to overlook: how is "dependency" (also "depend", "dependent") used in your context? The usage of parent-dependents pair is clear in the context of parenting/family. The usage of target-dependencies is also clear in the context of IT/programming/PM (sometimes target-prerequisites). The usage of parent-children, master-slave, etc. is also clear in other contexts. Because you use both "child" and "dependent", it could confuse your reader unless the meanings of these words are clear or made clear in your article.

Comment: @StoneyB "head" is what I selected, as the context is linguistic and NLP

Answer (score 2):

For your specific context, If X is dependant on Y, then Y is the **dependency**.

<sup>[[source]](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/12590/21740)</sup>

In normal use, this isn't particularly common, but in your software context, it seems fine to me as both a native speaker and a programmer.

Specifically in XML however, I would use the word "parent tag"

In other contexts you might want to use:

- provider
- supplier
- parent
- benefactor
- donor

Comment: Thank you, as my context is dependency structure in linguistic, I think **dependency node** works.

Comment: Just because it is a correct option, don't assume that all of your readers will understand. Personally I'd go for "parent tag/node". It's more likely to be widely understood. If in doubt, try and explain it to somebody who doesn't have knowledge in the subject and see if they understand.

Comment: What if I just leave it as it is? Also I added another version to say it in the question, if really using an adjective is ambiguous.

Comment: Both of your options are usable. I'd favour the latter of the two, but I'd still favour "parent-child" descriptions. It's something I'm used to as a programmer.

Comment: I found the word "head" and mentioned it to my answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

If your context is linguistic and languages, you can use "**head**" or "**governor**". for example in the sentence "I saw John", "saw" is the "head" and "I" and "John" are dependents.

Comment: But your context isn't linguistics. Your context is an XML document. The fact that the XML document contains information about linguistics is incidental.

Comment: Indeed when I read "head node", I think you mean "root node"

Comment: @JamesWebster But we don't have a "parent" node, we specify the "parent" of a node as the node containing the "head" for a "dependent". Then parent node is not clear for the reader but he knows the head for a dependent.